# FTDI driver installed but COM port is not appearing (Windows 7, 64bit)

Tags: windows-7, serial-port

I'm firmware engineer and using the FTDI chips a lot. Everything works great.
But today, with one device I have a problem.
In my colleague PC, the COM port of the device appears, but in other PCs in our company (checked on 5 computers with FTDI drivers installed) including mine it's not.
Looks like the FTDI chip is unconnected.
We tried to connected to other usb connectors of the PCs, but it steel doesn't appears.
We tried compleatly uninstall the drivers and install them again - the same result.

What could be a problem?
Some ways to understand what is wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm) are a few utilities provided by FTDI for troubleshooting purpose. You can try your luck with this. Also, this one seems to be more of software/driver issue as compared to electrical. I am not sure you will get much help here.

Comment: are you sure the COM port has an actual FTDI part? searching for "counterfeit FTDI COM port"  may yield info on potential problems

Comment: are you 100% sure the drivers have FINISHED installing... in the taskbar there should potentially a spinning symbol w.r.t. "installing drivers"... Windows managers drivers in a beyond retarded manner... you may have run the driver installer but that just stages the sys files. The OS then registers the drivers once the hardware is detected. If the PC is configured to search for driver from WindowsUpdate you can be stuck in a long wait... 50min sometimes. Skip it and use local

Comment: Hello, thank you all for the answers!
I'm sure, the driver finished installation.  
In my colleague computer the device works perfectly.  
All tested computers were used and used now for development for the hardware and have FTDI drivers installed.

Comment: The problem is that the all tested computers (except my colleague PC) completely don't see the device.

Comment: That's not what I am stating. The FTDI driver install is ... funky (coupled with windows annoying management of drivers). Plug the device into the machine having problems. Is the device listed in DeviceManager (even with a /!\ ) If not you have other issues. If it is listed, check the taskbar for windows device installation indication